# Using inspect.getmembers

Tags: python, inspect

I'm trying to use `inspect.getmembers` to check for classes and functions inside a file. The problem is that I don't know how to pass the name of the file to `inspect.getmembers` without using `import`. That's because I need to specify a different file name each time

The code looks similar to this:

```
def extractName(self,fileName):

    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(FileName):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):

            print "this is class",name


    if inspect.isfunction(obj):

        print "this is method",name
```

Comment: it sounds like you'd like to import a module based on it's name?

Comment: See the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path on how to get the module object of a python source file given its path.

Comment: Is the second `if` statement suppose to be inside of your `for` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to inspect a module, you *must* execute it somehow; otherwise, the definitions in the file won't be available.

You can use `module = __import__(modname)` to import a module by name, or `module = imp.load_source("__inspected__", path)` to import a module by path.

Comment: thanks for the answer , but the problem is that I want to let any one who run the program to specify file name that could be different each time.. so is there any way to do so??

Comment: That only works if you have the module's name, as in this case we don't. Instead with pathname which we have use: `imp.load_source("the value of this string doesn't matter", '/path/to/file.py')` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/67692

Comment: Thanks, added `imp.load_source`.